# Don't call db_disconnector automatically in dplyr

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I'm using tbl_sql object in my Shiny app to have access to a database table. I've noticed that sometimes dplyr close this connection. It might be because garbage collector calls db_disconnector. Is there any way to stop this? I could close the connection on the shiny close event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like, if you `d <- src_mysql(...)` (I guess that's the backend you're using, and how you're connecting to the data base?) then the garbage collector will only run if `d` goes out of scope. Maybe its the database that is timing out connections as a way to manage load?

One way to test this is to write your own wrapper (rather than `src_mysql()`) that does not disconnect

```
src_yoursql <-
    function (dbname, host = NULL, port = 0L, user = "root", password = "", 
              ...) 
{
    if (!requireNamespace("RMySQL", quietly = TRUE)) {
        stop("RMySQL package required to connect to mysql/mariadb", 
            call. = FALSE)
    }
    con <- DBI::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = dbname, host = host, 
        port = port, username = user, password = password, ...)
    info <- DBI::dbGetInfo(con)
    src_sql("mysql", con, info = info)
}

d = src_yoursql(...)
```

Close it manually with

```
DBI::dbDisconnect(d$con)
```